# Populating AutoComplete from WebService

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, web-services

I have managed to get a JQuery autocomplete working in C#.net using a webservice.

Here is the asp code:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <h3>
            Manage Season</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <p>
            <label class="control-label" for="TeamName">
                Team Name:</label></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TeamNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="searchinput"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="AddTeamButton" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Add"
            OnClick="AddTeamButton_Click" />
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".searchinput").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "PredictiveSearch.asmx/GetAllPredictions",
                    data: "{'keywordStartsWith':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);

                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the c# web service:

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PredictiveSearch : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public IList<string> GetAllPredictions(string keywordStartsWith)
    {
        //TODO: implement real search here!

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[findEnglishTeams]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        string searchTerm = keywordStartsWith;
        SqlParameter searchTermParam = new SqlParameter("@searchterm", searchTerm);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(searchTermParam);

        IList<string> output = new List<string>();

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (dReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dReader.Read())
            {
                output.Add(dReader["englishTeamName"].ToString());
            }
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return output; 
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the ID of the values i am populating the drop down with, how is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you elaborate? Do you mean how do you access `data.d` in the webservice response?

Comment: Well my data reader outputs the team names from the database, but I need to access the ID number of the team to add them into a league table

Comment: Is there a reason you are assigning it via classes and NOT using the id to start?  It would hint you have multiple textboxes you are wanting to bind to but I only see the need for one.  If it is the id's causing problems because asp is adding stuff to the id, use ClientIDMode="static".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are populating this on the Client Side using an Ajax request, you are going to have to either:

1. Get the selected value by writing it to a html input type=hidden element and reading it on the server side when the form posts back. Just don't forget to make the `input type=hidden` element a server-side control by adding `runat="server"`
2. Submit the selected value via another Ajax request.
3. Read the selected values using the Request.Params collection, using the listbox's name as the Key. Something like:

   ```
   var selectedValues = Request.Params["select_box_name"];
   ```

You won't be able to simply use `ListBox.SelectedValue` because the values won't be found in the `ViewState` since you are populating it via Ajax.

I'd go with option 3...

Answer (score 0):

Hope the something [like](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-implement-auto-complete-textbox.html) this serves your need better